# ServiceStack: Dependency Invocation

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have the following Service which has a dependency on another class which has an event.

```
public class DashboardService : SecureService
{
    private readonly DashboardAdapter _dashboardAdapter;
    private bool _isConnected;

    public DashboardService(DashboardAdapter dashboardAdapter)
    {
        _dashboardAdapter = dashboardAdapter;
        _dashboardAdapter.OnConnection += OnConnection;
    }

    public object Get(DashboardRequest request)
    {
        return new Dashboard { IsConnected = _isConnected };
    }

    private void OnConnection(object sender, ConnectionEventArgs e)
    {
        _isConnected = e.IsConnected;
    }
}
```

The problem is, the event is never firing, where as if I did the following, the event would fire and set my property appropriately:

```
    public object Get(DashboardRequest request)
    {
        var dashboard = new DashboardAdapter();
        dashboard.OnConnected += OnConnection;
        return new Dashboard { IsConnected = _isConnected };
    }
```

I have registered my adapter in the container like so:

```
var dashboard = new DashboardAdapter();
container.Register(dashboard);
```

Is there something I am missing or going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately what you have is very unlikely to work, because you have a number of race conditions.

#`DashboardService` doesn't exist long enough:

When you make a request to the `DashboardRequest` route an new instance of the `DashboardService` is created to handle that request.

This will setup the `OnConnection` method with your dependency, and ServiceStack will call your `Get` action method. But your action method code doesn't wait for that method to ever be triggered, and because of this a `DashboardService` is never likely to exist while an `OnConnected` event is fired.

```cs
public object Get(DashboardRequest request)
{
    // Should have waited here for the event to be triggered
    while(!_connected)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    
    return new Dashboard { IsConnected = _isConnected };
}
```

#Event occurs before or after the request
You have created a single instance of the `DashboardAdapter` which is registered with the container.

```cs
var dashboard = new DashboardAdapter();
container.Register(dashboard);
```

This means that the instance will be shared with all requests that inject it. But it also means that the instance could be changing state before a request is created to even listen for it. Or the event could try and fire between requests.

[image: Race]

So because you don't enquire as to the current state of `DashboardAdapter` when you create `DashboardService` then `_isConnected` may be wrong.

#`DashboardAdapter` created in the action method:

```cs
public object Get(DashboardRequest request)
{
    var dashboard = new DashboardAdapter();
    dashboard.OnConnected += OnConnection;
    return new Dashboard { IsConnected = _isConnected };
}
```

There is still a small race condition here, but it is more likely to work, because your event trigger is more likely to overlap with the existence of your `DashboardService`. This would be the equivalent of:

```cs
container.RegisterAutoWiredType(typeof(DashboardAdapter), ReuseScope.Request);
```

#Example:

[This console app gist](https://gist.github.com/scottmcarthur/d77e494e1a5e09ad0d08) shows a very rough example of waiting for the event to be triggered. It creates a single `DashboardAdapter` which will change it's `isConnected` state every 10 seconds, *even while no requests are being received*. When a request is made, it will wait to be notified of being connected, then output. *Note this is a v4 app but it is easily adaptable to v3*

---

###From chat discussion:

#Without an Event Handler:

[Chat Discussion History](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55372/discussion-of-24135776)

You probably don't need an event handler in the service, as the single `DashboardAdapter` instance that is in the `container` will continue to update it's state, and you can read this as required during the short lifecycle of the `DashboardService` instance.

`DashboardAdapter` using an `IsConnected` property.

```cs
public class DashboardAdapter
{
    readonly MyBrokerService service;
    public bool IsConnected { get; set; }

    public DashboardAdapter()
    {
        // Create your connection to the WCF broker service

        // Pseudo code for the connection, replace with your actual implementation
        service = new MyBrokerService();
        service.onConnectionStatusChanged += (sender, e) => {
            IsConnected = e.isConnected;
        };
    }
}
```

Then to check in the `DashboardService` is simply

```cs
public class DashboardService : SecureService
{
    private readonly DashboardAdapter _dashboardAdapter;

    public DashboardService(DashboardAdapter dashboardAdapter)
    {
        _dashboardAdapter = dashboardAdapter;
    }

    public object Get(DashboardRequest request)
    {
        return new Dashboard { IsConnected = _dashboardAdapter.IsConnected };
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a static property I can use to store the value of the IsConnected property and have the event fire in the AppHost constructor which sets it appropriately, then in my service I can look for that property?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, we've gone with the approach we discussed in chat and seems to be working a treat! If I could upvote more I would! :D